# Does the current iOS SDK for Facebook use OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am integrating Facebook Login into my app using the iOS SDK. The issue that I am having is my backend is telling me that I need to send the OAuth authorization code and redirect uri of the provider, which is Facebook in this case, to them for authenticate the user in our platform. So my question is does the Facebook iOS SDK do OAuth2 Authentication? If it does, how would I be able to access the OAuth authorization code and redirect uri? If not, is there a way to do OAuth2 Authentication for iOS using Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook iOS SDK will do all of the Oath for you. The way I do it in my app.

1. I'm calling a login function via Facebook SDK

   ```
   +(void)facebookLoginButtonClicked:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   [login logOut];
   [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"user_friends",@"email"] fromViewController:viewController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            Log(@"Process error: %@", error);
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            Log(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
            //Log(@"Logged in with results: %@", result);
            [self fetchCurrentUser:viewController];
        }
    }];
   }
   ```
2. Then I'm fetching current user with fields that I'm interested in:

   ```
   +(void)fetchCurrentUser:(UIViewController *)viewController{
   NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id,first_name,last_name,name,email,picture.width(100),friends.summary(true),link,permissions",@"fields", nil];

   if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
       [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:params]
        startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
              //  Log(@"fetched user:%@", result);
              // Here you can notify your backend service about new user
        }];
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Does the result contain the redirect_uri?

Comment: check the info.plist steps in facebook tutorial

Comment: Result doesn't contain redirect_uri. Results contaons requested information from the graph call. Make sure to follow getting started guide for properly configure your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: Facebook SDK does all of the authorization for you: it will ask the user to authorize the app. You don't have to write code for it.